# error trying to install rstudio shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to install RStudio Shiny dashboard following the instructions here:

http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html

But I get this error:

`devtools::install_github("rstudio/shinydashboard")
Downloading github repo rstudio/shinydashboard@master
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : <not set>`

Any ideas?

Comment: May be this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287685/devtoolsinstall-github-error-in-function-type-msg-aserror-true-not-se

Comment: I put it as an answer, the one below worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Ubuntu 14.10 laptop, it worked following the instructions here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23998908/719016

I first installed this package:

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Then in R:

`install.packages('RCurl')`

After that, I tried again to install the package with devtools:

`devtools::install_github("rstudio/shinydashboard")`

and it worked.